# Registering dll file extension

Tags: windows-7

System showing specified dll.application extension not found :
[image: System showing specified dll.application extension not found]

I tried installing Adobe Reader DC on my Windows 7 laptop and it couldn't load because the extension MSVCP120.dll was missing from my computer. I downloaded the extension and tried to register it, but the computer kept saying that the module msvcp120.dll failed to load and could not be found.

What should I do?

Comment: I hope you didn't download that from one of those garbage .dll download sites. You just need to download the 2013 Visual C++ Redistributable from Microsoft and install it.

Answer (score 0):

msvcp120.dll is part of the Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 12.0 redistributable runtime.

You can find it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784).